# Send a message to a specific user?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my discord bot send me a message every few hours, so I know it is still running.

For example:
The bot sends me 'Still functioning!' to me every two hours.

Here's some code I tried, but it didn't work:

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  client.user.setActivity("a game.");

  if (timeout) {
    clearInterval(timeout);
  }
  timeout = setInterval(() => client.channels.get("<ID Retracted>").send("Still functioning!"), 7200000);
  console.log("READY");
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
Jump to /app/index.js:26
    timeout = setInterval(() => client.channels.get("<retracted id>").send("Still functioning!"), 7200000);
                                                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Timeout.setInterval [as _onTimeout] (/app/index.js:26:74)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

Comment: What results and or errors did you subsequently get?

Comment: @rhand The error is now in the OP.

Comment: It looks that `client.channels.get("<retracted id>")` doesn't find a channel: if you try executing that in a command, does it get the channel?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`var fetchedUser = client.fetchUser(userID)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser) to fetch the user first, then you can call [`fetchedUser.createDM()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) to create and fetch a DM channel for the user.
Alternatively, the [`dmChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=dmChannel) property works too, though it would return null if a DM channel was not created previously between the bot and the user.

Comment: I got client.fetchUser to work, but I can't seem to get fetchedUser.createDM to work.
This is the code I did.
`client.fetchUser(293181883871920128)
 client.fetchedUser.createDM()`

I got this error:
https://pastebin.com/ss2F9q0z

Comment: Did u assign `fetchedUser`... Also, in my answer, I am assuming `fetchedUser` is a variable you assigned based on the return value of `client.fetchUser(userID)`, it is not something client has. I edited my answer to give prevent confusion

Comment: Still not working.
I did this:
``var fetchedUser = client.fetchUser(<userid>)
fetchedUser.createDM()``
and I ended up getting this:
https://pastebin.com/c7P2qXn3

Comment: Apparently `client.fetchUser(<userid>) ` returns a `promise<user>`, which means you need to [await for that operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). my bad on that one.

Answer (score 0):

To DM yourself that the bot is still running, you can use this code to make it DM you at the interval that you specified.

First, store your user ID as a varaible. For this example, I've made it **yourid**.

```
let yourid = client.users.get("your id")
```

Then make a function for the interval to run, I've named it intervalFunc for this example.

```
function intervalFunc() {
yourchannel.send("Im still running!")
}
```

Then last but not least, run the function at your interval.

```
setInterval(intervalFunc, 40000)
})
```

So, in the end, you'll have this code.

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
    client.on("ready", () => {
      client.user.setActivity("a game.");
    let yourchannel = client.users.get("your id")
    function intervalFunc() {
    yourchannel.send("Im still running!")
    }
    setInterval(intervalFunc, 40000)
    })
```

To send a message in a specific channel, its basically the same thing, only you are changing the `users.get` to a `channels.get`. I'll use **yourchannel** as the variable for the channel.

```
let yourchannel = client.channels.get("your id")
```

So, in the end you will get this code.

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
client.on("ready", () => {
  client.user.setActivity("a game.");
let yourchannel = client.channels.get("your id")
function intervalFunc() {
yourchannel.send("Im still running!")
}
setInterval(intervalFunc, 7200000)
})
```

These methods work because you already know what channel or DM channel you are working with. So, you can get their respective IDs and tell the bot to send your message at an interval in them. Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me.
``/app/index.js:26

  timeout = setInterval(() => ownerid.send("I'm still running!"), 60000);

                                      ^


TypeError: ownerid.send is not a function

at Timeout.setInterval [as _onTimeout] (/app/index.js:26:39)

    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)

    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)

    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)

    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)

``

Comment: Weird, let me see if I can reproduce the error and fix it.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to actually even get the channel ID, big mistake on my part. Will update the solution to a working one.